# Quarantine On/Of

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

I have a question about the prepositions that go with "*quarantine*":

> [link](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2014/oct/24/ebola-quarantine-new-york-new-jersey-west-africa)
>   Doctors Without Borders, which Spencer had been working for in Guinea, said earlier on Friday that ***a quarantine on medics*** returning from Ebola-stricken countries would be an excessive measure.

Would replacing "*a quarantine* ***on*** *medics*" with "*a quarantine* ***of*** *medics*" be better?  How are they different?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where neither would be wrong. It may be subtly different depending on the subject of your sentence/paragraph, like so.

When the quarantine is the subject:

> The quarantine is being placed on the medics, it's a quarantine on medics

When the medics are the subject

> The medics are being quarantined, it's a quarantine of medics

This is because a quarantine is a noun of something which is 'placed', but is also a verb of the action 'to quarantine' - similar to 'a tax' on earnings and 'to tax' earnings. This allows a little more flexibility in the use of the word.

In your example, the subject of the sentence is the concept of a quarantine, but neither use would be considered wrong.

Comment: I suppose there might be something in your distinction, but I think most people would neither notice nor care if you reversed the usage in your examples. There are a couple of dozen results each in Google Books for *a quarantine **on/of** people*, and I can't see any particular distinction between the different contexts.

Comment: Yeah if you note the main point of my answer is that it doesn't matter, neither would be wrong. I thought it worthwhile to explain the subtlety for extra detail, in case the original poster or another reader finds the context interesting

Comment: I'd guess much the same uncertainty over which preposition to use applies to *curfew*, and probably several other words. Relatively uncommon usages like this often don't have very fixed grammar. Unfortunately, we may be seeing a lot more "quarantine on/of ebola" in the coming months.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Story says, both are used by authors these days. But...IMO...

Enforcing words like *'ban'* and *'quarantine'* when used for nouns is ***generally*** seen with the preposition *'on'*. Something like *"ban **on** dogs in the park"* and not *"...of dogs..."*

In [Bradenton's article](http://www.bradenton.com/2014/10/27/5439075/illinois-gov-candidates-agree.html#storylink=cpy) *"Gov. Pat Quinn and Republican challenger Bruce Rauner agree on imposing a quarantine **on** people returning..."*

However, we do find examples of *"quarantine **of..."*** as in [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/oct/26/white-house-christie-cuomo-ebola-quarantine).

Comment: *Ban* and *quarantine* have different tendencies: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=34123163

Comment: @snailboat I do understand that but I'm talking about the same context wherein we enforce something on someone.